# Binding XML nodes to a Gridview C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a project in which data is stored in an xml document and then displayed in an asp.net gridview. Each column represents a different node in the file. However I have reached a situation in which I have multiple of some of the nodes so I need some advice on how this can be achieved.

Lets suppose the xml file is a record of books in a bookstore (example from w3 schools):

```
<book category="web">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
```

As you can see in this example there are numerous authors, so if I have multiple of a node (in this case author) how could i load those into a gridview? Would it be recommended to name each node i.e. author 1, author 2, author 3 etc? Or is it possible to make a child node i.e.

```
    <author>
         <name1> </name1>
         <name2> </name2>
         <name3> </name3>
    </author>
```

The final important thing is that these nodes I want to create may themselves have several attributes. So to keep to this above example it may be a date and place of birth of each author listed.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Quick question while I try to figure out a good answer for you... do you have control over the format of the xml you are getting? Also, do you have to use a GridView?

Comment: Hi James - I have full control over the creation and format of the xml file, the only requirement is that it has to be an xml document that will be displayed in a gridview. The reason for this is that this is an additional bit of work which is an expansion of a web application already in use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start off by saying there are a lot of different ways to do this. Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, I'll give you something that is pretty flexible & easy, but perhaps not the most concise or "correct" way. A better solution would involve writing queries against your data and then displaying the resulting rows, but that may be overkill for your purpose. I will not demonstrate that here.

Ideally you would structure your xml more like the following.

```
<books>
    <book category='web'>
        <title lang='en'>XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <authors>
            <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
            <author>thomas waterloo</author>
            <author>malinda gatesauthor>
            <author>rusty weatherford</author>
        <authors>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
</books>
```

Secondly, a GridView doen't really like to bind to nested data. There is definitely a way to do it, but you'll be better off just looping through the data and printing it to the screen. Alternatively, you could investigate using a Repeater control.

Try out the following code. I was able to get this running in a new asp.net web forms project.

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <table>
    <% foreach ( XmlNode book in myNodes) { %>
            <tr>
            <% foreach ( XmlNode childElement in book ) {
                   string title = null;
                   string year = null;
                   string price = null;
                   List<string> authors = new List<string>();

                   switch (childElement.Name)
                   {
                       case "title":
                           title = childElement.InnerText.ToString();
                           break;
                       case "year":
                           year = childElement.InnerText.ToString();
                           break;
                       case "price":
                           price = childElement.InnerText.ToString();
                           break;
                       case "authors":
                           foreach (XmlNode grandChildElement in childElement)
                           {
                               authors.Add(grandChildElement.InnerText);
                           }
                           break;
                   }%>

                    <td><label><%= title %></label></td>
                    <td><label><%= year %></label></td>
                    <td><label><%= price %></label></td>
                    <td>
                        <%foreach( string author in authors ){ %>
                            <label> <%= author %></label><br />
                        <% } %>
                    </td>
            <% } %>
            </tr>
    <% } %>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected XmlNodeList myNodes = null;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string booksXml = @"<books>
                <book category='web'>
                    <title>Columbus Sailed the Ocean Blue</title>
                    <year>1492</year>
                    <price>6 gold doubloons</price>
                    <authors>
                        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
                        <author>john doe</author>
                        <author>jane doe</author>
                    </authors>
                </book>
                <book category='web'>
                    <title>Best Book Ever</title>
                    <year>1776</year>
                    <price>23.55</price>
                    <authors>
                        <author>Robert Frost</author>
                    </authors>
                </book>
                <book category='web'>
                    <title>Hello World!</title>
                    <year>20013</year>
                    <price>49.99</price>

                </book>
                <book category='web'>
                    <title>1234</title>
                    <year>1999</year>
                    <price>69.99</price>
                    <authors>
                        <author>Carmen SanDiego</author>
                        <author>Roger Rabbit</author>
                    </authors>
                </book>
            </books>";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(booksXml);

            //doc.ChildNodes[0] is the entire books element and al of its children
            //doing .ChildNodes again gives you all of the book elements
            this.myNodes = doc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes;
        }
    }
}
```

Using the innertext property will break down if your node structure gets more complex, but I'll leave fixing that to you. Hope this helps!

Comment: James, thanks for your efforts! I'm not sure this will do the trick. I am restrained to using an xml file and a gridview (as the current application does this to display data). The problem I have is that the additional work requires displaying data which, in some cases, has "lists" or "multiple entries" for a given xml node. The data which is displayed in the gridview is then used to format a JSON string to interact with a remote api. The method used so far is to do an xmlread on page load then bind that data to the gridview - which worked well until the multiple values for a given property!

Comment: I think my best option may be to use a repeater within the gridview column to display the nested data so thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: I've added a new answer using your preferred approach. Let me know if it's closer to what you were looking for or how I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I've given it another shot based on your responses. Here i read the xml straight out of a file & then bind to a GridView with a Repeater nested inside of it.

The only trick you need here (demonstrated below) is to monitor the RowDataBound event on the GridView & then for each row go and find which authors belong to that row.

The xml file books.xml

```
<books>
    <book category='web'>
        <title>Columbus Sailed the Ocean Blue</title>
        <year>1492</year>
        <price>6 gold doubloons</price>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
        <author>john doe</author>
        <author>jane doe</author>
    </book>
    <book category='web'>
        <title>Best Book Ever</title>
        <year>1776</year>
        <price>23.55</price>
        <author>Robert Frost</author>
    </book>
    <book category='web'>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
        <year>20013</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category='web'>
        <title>1234</title>
        <year>1999</year>
        <price>69.99</price>
        <author>Carmen SanDiego</author>
        <author>Roger Rabbit</author>
    </book>
</books>
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>



<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="myGridView_RowDataBound" >
         <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <label> Title: <%# Eval("title")%></label>
                     <label> Year:<%# Eval("year")%></label>
                     <label> Price:<%# Eval("price")%></label>
                     <asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
                          <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <thead>Authors: </thead>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server"><%# Eval("author_Text")%></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            </table>
                            <br />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                     </asp:Repeater>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        DataTableCollection tables = null;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("C:\\dev\\books.xml");

            //ds.Tables[0] is the books table
            //ds.Tables[1] is the authors table
            // When reading xml into a DataSet object, the data is normalized (think SQL-like)
            myGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            tables = ds.Tables;
            myGridView.DataBind();
        }

        protected void myGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Repeater repeater = (Repeater)e.Row.FindControl("myRepeater");

                // Because our data is now in tables, we need to join the tables based on the book_Id identifier
                // The columns named book_Id in table 0 and table 1 were both created for us automatically to link up the data
                // when we read the xml into the DataSet object.
                var authors = tables[1].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["book_Id"] as int? == e.Row.DataItemIndex).AsDataView();

                repeater.DataSource = authors;
                repeater.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```